# List ArcGIS geodatabase feature classes on Python console

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase

I am trying to create a new script with a hard-coded geodatabase filename, that lists the feature classes it contains to the console.
I know there are several ways to do this, but I decided to to use ListFeatureClasses function.

I got the following sample code from ArcGIS website, but I do not know what changes I need to make in order for it to work.
I barely started studying Python, so I know very basic stuff, but I would like to get help with this.

```
import os
import arcpy

# Set the workspace for ListFeatureClasses
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/base"

# Use the ListFeatureClasses function to return a list of
# shapefiles.
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# Copy shapefiles to a file geodatabase
for fc in featureclasses:
 arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(
  fc, os.path.join("c:/base/output.gdb",
   os.path.splitext(fc)[0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
"c:/base"
```

to be the path to your file geodatabase.  Eg, `"C:/path/to/database.gdb"`

Change

```
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(
      fc, os.path.join("c:/base/output.gdb",
       os.path.splitext(fc)[0]))
```

to:

```
    print fc
```